# org capture at point as sibling of heading

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

org 9.2 used to support this feature. when `(org-capture 0)`, it used to place the selected template entry as a sibling of heading at point. in org 9.3 however, it fully respects the heading level defined in the template.

How can I automatically shift the level of the template heading to match the heading at point?

Comment: This sounds to me like  a bug: I bisected and found out that it was introduced by [this commit](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/commit/0201d1c0cc367fea0e561ba113f02f263b0ed501) about a year ago. I'll report a bug on the mailing list and add a pointer here to track its progress.

Comment: Bug report is at https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2020-08/msg00062.html

Comment: Thanks for looking into it and reporting. didn't figure it would be a bug but a feature.

Comment: That's what I think, but the maintainers may disagree :) But it's out there, so we'll see.

Comment: This has been fixed (supposedly: I have not tested the fix) with [this commit](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/commit/f5573e6a00ba649f8da390e280374d172dc7dd77).

Comment: @nickD thanks for following up.

Answer (score 0):

modified from [File org-capture entry under current headline at point](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/58008/file-org-capture-entry-under-current-headline-at-point)

```lisp
  ;; Create ‘C-u 2 M-x org-capture’ command to refile org-capture template under
  ;; headline at point.
  (defvar my-org-capture-rfloc nil
    "Holds the RFLOC argument to pass to ‘org-refile’.")
  (defun my-org-capture-under-headline (&optional goto keys under-heading)
    "Capture a headline using ‘org-capture’, according to the template you \
  select, and then immediately refile that headline under the headline at the \
  current point.  GOTO and KEYS are passed to ‘org-capture’."
    (interactive "P")
    (unwind-protect
        (progn
          (unless (eq major-mode 'org-mode)
            (user-error "Must be called from an Org-mode buffer"))
          ;; Capture refile target at point. For format see
          ;; ‘org-refile-target-table’.
          (setq my-org-capture-rfloc
                (list
                 (org-display-outline-path t t nil t)
                 (buffer-file-name (buffer-base-buffer))
                 nil
                 (org-with-wide-buffer
                  (org-back-to-heading t)
                  (point-marker))))
          (funcall #'org-capture goto keys)
          (when my-org-capture-rfloc
            (save-excursion 
              (org-capture-goto-last-stored)
              ;; Refile last-captured target under the headline stored earlier.
              (org-refile nil nil my-org-capture-rfloc)
              ;; Ensure point is at the newly-captured and refiled headline.
              (org-refile-goto-last-stored)
              (unless under-heading
                (outline-promote)))
            ))
      ;; Ensure ‘my-org-capture-rfloc’ is reset.
      (setq my-org-capture-rfloc nil)))
  (defun my-org-capture-under-headline-prefix (_orig-fn &rest _args)
    "Provide an additional “C-u 2” prefix arg to `org-capture'.

  When ‘org-capture’ is called with this prefix argument, it will capture a
  headline according to the template you select, and then immediately refile that
  headline under the headline at the current point."
    (let ((goto (nth 0 _args)))
      (if (equal goto 2)
          (apply #'my-org-capture-under-headline _args)
        (apply _orig-fn _args))))
  (advice-add 'org-capture :around #'my-org-capture-under-headline-prefix)
```

under-heading controls whether the new heading is a sibling or a child of the current heading.

```lisp
 (global-set-key (kbd "C-c k") (lambda () (interactive) (my-org-capture-under-headline 0 "b" nil))) ;;as a sibling of current heading
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-c j") (lambda () (interactive) (my-org-capture-under-headline 0 "b" t))) ;; as a child of current heading
```